# Community promotion ads

Tags: discussion

Shall we start a small advertising campaign?

Some Stack Exchange communities vote on “community ads” — banners that link to other resources related to the topic. Highly voted proposals get free ad display time on that community. [Here’s an example](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3689/166) for an ad for the “[Genealogy SE (beta)](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/) that’s displayed on the [Biology.SE site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).

I suggest creating a similar banner for out budding Bioinformatics site and suggesting it on some Stack Exchange sites — for example, Biology, Stats, Chemistry (?) etc. (Unfortunately not all sites have community ads, and in particular Stack Overflow doesn’t.)

For this, we will need:

- A banner design
- A tagline (to be displayed on mouseover)

Comment: Yesh! Great idea! I hope someone else can come up with a nice banner. If not, I'll do it but given my complete lack of any talent in that respect, I'd really prefer if someone else could.

Comment: Great idea, can you add a ss of that ad?

Comment: Nice idea, I also think anything tagged with 'bioinformatics' on SO could potentially be directed towards here, even if just via a comment

Comment: Unfortunately I’m (a) not a graphic designer, and (b) short of time at the moment (too many projects at once). Unfortunately it doesn’t seem as if anybody else is up for creating a banner.

Comment: Are you all still interested in doing something like this? I'm pretty handy with Illustrator and could try to put something together.

Comment: @Geraldine_VdAuwera Absolutely, that would be great. I’m currently not very active in online communities due to other commitments, but I’ll happily upvote and promote community ad designs.

Answer (score 2):

Alright I was playing around and made this nerdy old-school graphic which I'm embarrassed to share, but maybe it can serve as a conversation starter to figure out what direction we want to take on this.

[image: proposed ad graphic showing "bioinfx" with DNA, RNA and protein, plus a terminal like part with the community URL]

Comment: I’m not sure about the tag line, but I do like pretty much all of the rest. However, I just noticed that [the last “community ads” activity from Stack Exchange was in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads?tab=Newest), and I’m now wondering whether that programme actually still exists.

Comment: OK, [community ads are still active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344512/1968)!

Comment: That's a relief :)
Yeah I agree the corny tagline is meh.

Answer (score 0):

Exciting.

I think if @KonradRudophs advice is followed this is a positive step toward 'lift off', i.e. moving out of beta version. The site has been on 5 questions per day for some time now (minimum threshold for 'lift off') and this seems to be a function of the total number of views per day which is now around 2K to a maximum of 2.5K per day. As a whole the traffic here is increasing and promotion can only help.

@GeraldineVdAuwera graphic looks fine, thank you, and good enough for a  banner. It could always be upgraded modified later. I wouldn't worry about the polish at present, considering we're essentially 'backend developers' rather than 'frontend designers'.

Could the 'icon' for bioinfo.SE be upgraded?